# Cannot enable CSS3 transforms on Chromium under Ubuntu

Tags: linux, css, webgl, chromium

I read a lot about this, i've seen a lot of examples but after following the simple instructions for enabling 3d transforms and webgl I cannot get it to work. Everywhere says that the trick is to execute "`chromium-browser --enable-accelerated-compositing --enable-webgl`", but it doesn't seem to work! I've the latest daily build, which is Chromium 9.0.592 under Ubuntu 10.4, any ideas?

Comment: migrate to http://askubuntu.com/?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked before Chrome 10 came out, but for what it's worth, I just viewed this page with Chrome 10 on Ubuntu, and see that there's at least partial support for 3d CSS transformations:

http://desandro.github.com/3dtransforms/examples/perspective-01.html

Specifically, I see the red square "rotated" in the y axis.
[image]